# SMS Alerts for SharePoint

Tags: wss-3.0, alert

How do I implement SMS Alerts for tasks assigned in SharePoint?

Is there a web part or feature available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no such feature inbuilt into SharePoint which can provide you SMS notifications. However you can implement such service in conjuction with the OOB alert service. This again would require a lot of development efforts.

Answer (score 4):

This is built in to SharePoint 2010

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/08/send-sms-for-alert-in-sharepoint-2010.html

> In central administration, you need to provide the URL of SMS service,
>   credentials. You can check the SMS service by hitting the test service
>   button.
>
> It works over Office Mobile Service Protocol like mail uses SMTP. This
>   OMS actually allows client to send text and multimedia messages to
>   server which processes the request and sends to the destination mobile
>   number.
>
> Even the SMS can also be replied and service can then deliver this
>   reply in terms of SMTP mail.

Comment: Ryan, could you add the essential parts of the answer here, and leave the link for reference? See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

There are third party services out there which you can sign up to, to send SMS messages, and which expose an API (like Esendex).

Depending on what it is you need to send SMS messages on you could couple a feature to esendex or something similar to send out SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint App Store has an App (add-in)   : **SMS for Office (Send SMS Via SharePoint List)**

- There are zero configurations required from your end (no creating
  accounts with SMS providers)
- Install the add-in and you will get a
  SharePoint list in your site, where you can start sending SMS.
- For SMS Alerts , you would have to make use of SharePoint Designer
  workflow to create an list item entry in the SMS List. (You can use
  the default SharePoint Create a list item action here)
- A completelist of features is available in the company website here : https://timeparity.com/sms-sharepoint
- You can also Search for the app directly in *SharePoint Store (Office Store), the add-in name is "SMS for Office(SMS via SharePoint List)*

[image: Sending SMS From SharePoint]